# Sql MAX DateTime and if clause?

Tags: sql-server, sql

My 2nd Sql question on SO today - I need to brush up my Sql skills!!!!

I have the following three tables....

Diary, Entry, and EntryType

A Diary can have many Entry(ies), each Entry is of a particular EntryType.

Entry has a created DateTime
EntryType has an Id, and SomeOtherValue (int)

**EDIT**

Sorry Chaps.  Thanks for response so far but I didn't explain it well enough; the requirements have changed a bit.....

I would like the Id of any Diary where its latest Entry that is greater than @lastDateTime AND EntryType.someOthervalue != 0 has a EntryType.someOthervalue == @someValue

Or to put it another way....For all those Entry rows with a created Date time > @lastDateTime, ignore the someOtherValues that equal 0, and if the top 1 left over has a someOtherValue = @someValue, return the Id of the diary!!!!

Does that make sense???  I'm not sure what I should be putting my MAX, WHERE, and HAVING (if anything at all!)

Thanks,

ETFairfax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the last entry, and then `with the last entry`, test whether the entrytype of that last entry is @somevalue, then this should be the right query

```
select diaryid
from (
    select rn=row_number() over (partition by e.diaryid order by e.created desc),
        d.diaryid, et.someothervalue
    from entry e
    inner join entrytype et on e.entrytype = et.id
    where e.created > @lastDateTime
) X
where rn=1
  and SomeOtherValue = @someValue -- of the last record
```

If however, you mean, among the entry types of @somevalue, is the latest one >@lastDateTime, then it is

```
select e.diaryid
from entry e
inner join entrytype et on e.entrytype = et.id
where et.SomeOtherValue = @someValue
group by e.diaryid
having max(e.created) > @lastDateTime
```

Note: For a db with proper references, the diary_id can be derived from entry `without going back to diary`. The only reason for linking back to diary is if you need the full diary record, or if there is no foreign key and you need to validate that the diary_id exists.

For the 2nd type, there is another way to write this that is still ANSI compliant and **may be faster**.  This works by deducing that for the MAX e.created to be greater than @lastdatetime, ANY record

**EDIT:** As Andriy points out for the 2nd query (directly preceeding this statement), the HAVING clause can be moved to the WHERE clause based on the same fact, but I have left the query in that form to match the expression of the requirements (not using the deduced simplification).

```
select e.diaryid
from entry e
where exists (
    select *
    from entrytype et
    where e.entrytype = et.id
      and et.SomeOtherValue = @someValue)
  and e.created > @lastDateTime
GROUP BY e.diaryid
```

This `EXIST`ential test can stop inspecting entrytypes for an entry as soon as it finds one matching somevalue and created instead of fully processing the join and aggregating (max) before filtering it down in the HAVING clause.

Comment: Your third approach should probably use `DISTINCT` or grouping: I don't think there's a reason to select duplicate `diaryid` values (which are possible there). And in your second one I think it would be valid and possibly better in terms of performance to convert the `having` condition to `where`, i.e. `where` would then look like this: `where et.SomeOtherValue = @someValue and e.created > @lastDateTime`. Nevetheless, it's a good point not to use `diary` in a query like this and the reason for doing otherwise was worth mentioning too. +1

Comment: @Andriy - thanks for the comment, I have added `group by` to the 3rd query (2nd approach for 2nd interpretation). The 2nd and 3rd mean different things from the first. The 2nd is deliberately written to express the question exactly - find all the entries of type X, then compare the MAX created from that result against @date, so I will leave that alone.

Comment: Although my original post changed a little, this response contained a load of information that helped me finally achieve what I needed. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
select d.diary_id
  from diary       d
  join entry       e on(d.diary_id = e.diary_id)
  join entry_type et on(e.entry_type_id = et.entry_type_id)
 where et.someOthervalue = @someValue
 group by d.diary_id
having max(e.created) > @lastDateTime;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach if you are using SQL Server 2005+

```
With EntryDates As
    (
    Select E.DiaryId
        , Max(E.Created) Over ( Partition By E.DiaryId ) As LastCreateDate
    From Entry As E
        Join EntryType As ET
            On ET.Id = E.EntryTypeId
    Where ET.SomeOtherValue = @SomeValue
    )
Select DiaryId 
From EntryDates
Where LastCreateDate > @lastDateTime
Group By DiaryId
```

Comment: FYI, windowing aggregates like `Max() OVER` can KILL performance. I've seen it. Adding an extra CTE with a real Max and a GROUP BY totally rescued my query one time.

Answer (score 0):

Diary, Entry, and EntryType

```
SELECT
FROM
   Diary D
   CROSS APPLY (
      SELECT TOP 1 E.EntryID
      FROM
         Entry E
      WHERE
         D.DiaryID = E.DiaryID
         AND E.CreatedDatetime > @LastDateTime
         AND EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 FROM EntryType ET
            WHERE E.EntryTypeID = ET.EntryTypeID
            AND ET.SomeOtherValue <> 0 -- or = @SomeValue ?
         )
      ORDER BY CreatedDatetime DESC
   )
```

An index in Entry on CreatedDatetime would be helpful, but either the table's clustered index should have DiaryID or the index should contain it as one of the indexed columns.

I presume the EntryTypeID table is small compared to the others, so it's most likely going to be a table scan anyway, so indexes won't help much. If your execution plan gets some high number of reads on the EntryType table, please let me know and we'll try to fix it. I'm hoping the engine is smart enough to realize this table is small and only hits it up once, and puts it on the left side of a LOOP join somewhere.

Please let me know how this goes and if it's not working right I'll tweak it. I'm sure we can get a really nicely-performing query going.